# ¿Porque una funcion recibe doble asterisco (**) de un puntero como parametros?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

En este programa, se envia como parametros en el switch la dirección de memoria de las variables locales, pero porque en la función se recibe (**) y no solo un *

```
#include <iostream.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <conio.h>

// preparando el nodo con dato y dirección de memoria

struct nodo{

int info;

nodo *sgt;

};



void agrega(nodo **cab, nodo **fin);

void muestra(nodo *cab);



void muestra1(nodo *cab){

cout<<"elementos en la lista"<<endl;

nodo* temp;

temp=cab;

while ( temp != NULL){

cout<<temp->info<<"   "<<temp->sgt<<endl;

temp=temp->sgt;

}

getch();

}

int main()

{ nodo *c=NULL,*f=NULL;  //puntero de cabecera, y puntero de fin de lista

  int opcion;

   do{

   system("cls");

   cout<<"1) Ingresa un dato (numero entero)."<<endl;

   cout<<"2) Muestra los datos ingresados   ."<<endl;

   cout<<"3) MOSTRAR CON DIRECCION          ."<<endl;

   cout<<"4) FIN                            ."<<endl;

  cout<<"ingrese opcion"<<endl;

  cin>>opcion;

  switch(opcion){

  case 3: muestra1(c);break;

  case 1: agrega(&c, &f);break;

  case 2: muestra(c);break;



  }

  }

  while(opcion!=4);

      system("PAUSE");

      return 0;

}

void agrega(nodo **cab, nodo **fin){

int num;

cout<<"ingrese informacion"<<endl;

cin>>num;

if((*cab)==NULL){

*cab = new nodo;

(*cab)->info =num;

(*cab)->sgt=NULL;

(*fin)=(*cab);

}else{

(*fin)->sgt=new nodo;

(*fin)->sgt->info=num;

(*fin)=(*fin)->sgt;

(*fin)->sgt=NULL;

}

}

void muestra(nodo *cab){

cout<<"elementos en la lista"<<endl;nodo* temp;

temp=cab;

while ( temp != NULL){

cout<<temp->info<<"   ";

temp=temp->sgt;

}

getch();

}
```

Comment: En pocas palabras  el doble asterisco es un puntero que apunta hacia otro puntero

Answer (score 0):

Los punteros son esencialmente números que indican posiciones de memoria.

Los tipos de los punteros a diferencia de las variables normales, no son necesarios. Por ello existe el tipo `void*`.

Pero encontrarás el inconveniente de que no puedes desreferenciarlos (escribir o leer en la posición de memoria guardada).

Esto porque el tipo determina el tamaño que ocupan y cómo codificar en memoria los valores que pueda tomar.

---

Para que lo puedas entender de una mejor manera te daré un ejemplo.

```
#include <iostream>

int n1 = 10;
int n2 = 15;

// Un puntero que apunta a la posición de la variable numero
int *ptrNumero = &n1;
// Si lo imprimes verás que obtienes una dirección de memoria
std::cout << "ptrNumero = " << ptrNumero << "\n";
// Si desreferencias verás que el valor que lee es el mismo que n1
std::cout << "n1 = " << n1 << "\n";
std::cout << "*ptrNumero = " << *ptrNumero << "\n";

// Un puntero que apunta al puntero ptrNumero
int **ptrPtrNumero = &ptrNumero;
// Si lo desreferencias verás que muestra la misma dirección que ptrPuntero
std::cout << "*ptrPtrNumero = " << *ptrPtrNumero << "\n";
// Si desreferencias está nueva dirección de memoria obtendrás el valor de n1
std::cout << "**ptrPtrNumero = " << **ptrPtrNumero << "\n";

// Si escribes un nuevo valor a la dirección que apunta ptrPtrNumero estarás cambiando el valor de ptrNumero
**ptrPtrNumero = &n2;
// Si lo desreferencias ahora verás que su valor es 15 porque está apuntando a n2
std::cout << "*ptrNumero = " << *ptrNumero << "\n";
```

Cómo puedes ver los punteros te dan bastante libertad aunque se vuelven difíciles de escribir cuántas más indirecciones uses.

Comment: Muchas gracias!