# Qué significa esta asignación?

Tags: c, define

Estaba mirando un código ajeno y me encuentro la siguiente macro:

`#define VARIABLE   (*(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD))`

Cabe destacar que `vuint8` está declarado como `typedef volatile uint8` en otro script.

En realidad mi pregunta es que no sé qué valor coge `VARIABLE` o cómo es el proceso lógico de asignación para esa macro.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un valor cualquiera expresado en hexadecimal

```
0x1234ABCD
```

A continuación lo tratas como si fuese una direción de memoria. Esa dirección de memoria, para más información, asumimos que va a almacenar un elemento de tipo `vuint8`

```
(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD)
```

Finalmente recuperamos el valor que se encuentra en dicha dirección de memoria

```
(*(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD))
```

Si lo hiciésemos con código podríamos crear el siguiente ejemplo:

```
vuint8* ptr = 0x1234ABCD;
vuint8 value = *ptr;
```

Comment: Vale... lo único que no entiendo es que almacena una variable de tipo `vint8`, cuando `0x1234ABCD` es de 32 bits en vez de 8. ¿O al manejar punteros simplemente esta accediendo la posición de memoria marcada por `0x1234ABCD`?

Comment: @Londo Correcto

Comment: @Londo probablemente sea una macro para detectar la [extremidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) de la arquitectura.

Comment: @Londo `0x1234ABCD` es la dirección de memoria. Un puntero es una variable que guarda una dirección de memoria. En esta respuesta lo explico https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/520082/169744

Comment: Muchas gracias por resolverme la duda!

Answer (score 2):

> Estaba mirando un código ajeno y me encuentro la siguiente macro:
>
> ```
> #define VARIABLE   (*(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD))
> ```
>
> Cabe destacar que `vuint8` está declarado como `typedef volatile uint8` en otro script.

Vamos a analizar la expresión `(*(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD))`:

1. `(vuint8 *)` es una conversión de tipos, quiere que lo que haya a la derecha de esa conversión se convierta a puntero a `vuint8`.
2. `(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD)` convierte el literal `0x1234ABCD` a puntero a `vuint8`.
3. `(* ...)` es el operador unario de *contenido-de*, sirve para obtener el valor contenido en un puntero.
4. `(*(vuint8 *)(0x1234ABCD))` convierte el literal `0x1234ABCD` a puntero a `vuint8` y obtiene su contenido.

Sin conocer el contexto de uso, deduzco que es una macro para averiguar la [extremidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) de los datos de la arquitectura en que se compila, por ejemplo:

```
if (VARIABLE == 0x12)
    printf("Big endian\n");
else if (VARIABLE == 0xCD)
    printf("Little endian\n");
else
    printf("Unknown endian\n");
```

En cuanto a marcar el tipo como [`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile), muy probablemente sea para evitar que el compilador aplique optimizaciones que podrían afectar a la utilidad de la macro para detectar *extremidad*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por resolverme la duda!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pensar las macros como variables normales. Solo que las macros existen únicamente hasta el preprocesado y no tienen tipo.

Las macros son meramente texto. Durante el preprocesado, cada aparición es reemplazada por el texto con el que se ha definido.

Esto:

```
int i = 10;
```

Sería análogo a:

```
#define I 10
```

Como puedes ver, las macros se crean usando `#define`, seguidas por el nombre y su valor.

---

Otra cosa que puedes hacer con las macros son funciones simples como:

```
 #define SALUDA(x) printf("Hola %s", x);
```

Lo que hace es reemplazar `SALUDA()` por `printf("Hola %s", x);` y la `x` por el parámetro.

Comment: El empleo de macros lo entiendo, lo que no acabo de pillar es el significado que cobran los punteros en esa línea