# Como implementar punteros para buscar un numero especifico en un arreglo

Tags: array, c, punteros

La explicacion de mi codigo es que el usuario debe ingresar el tamaño del arreglo, ingresar numeros que se guardaran y luego se mostraran mas adelante en el orden que fueron ingresados.

Mi pregunta es: Podria ser posible implementar punteros para ubicar un numero en un arreglo? Y de ser posible como seria o que tendria que hacer? El tema de punteros me resulta algo complicado, agradezco la ayuda de ante mano

Mi codigo:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
int tama=0, indice=0;

    printf("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tama);

    //declaracion del arreglo

    int arreglo[tama];
    for(indice=0; indice<=tama-1; indice++){
        printf ("Ingrese los valores: ");
        scanf ("%d", &arreglo[indice]);
    }

    //impresion de los valores ingresados
    printf ("\nLos valores ingresados fueron:");
    for(indice=0; indice<tama; indice++){

        printf("[%d] ", arreglo[indice]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Respuesta a la primera pregunta: me refiero a buscar un numero usando puntero y creo que si devolverlo como puntero. Perdon si no me explico bien, es que la verdad entiendo como funcionan los punteros pero aplicarlos no sabria como

**edit**
Otra pregunta: podría acceder a los valores almacenados en la matriz del programa principal a través una función usando punteros?

Comment: Te refieres a buscar un elemento y devolver un puntero a él o algo así?

Comment: Si no sabes bien lo que es un puntero podrías comenzar averiguando eso. Hay videos, preguntas, libros y diferentes recursos de los que puedes aprender. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/520082/169744) lo expliqué brevemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entonces, devuelve un puntero al número encontrado en el array, y este puntero se utilizará para acceder al valor del número encontrado.

Declarando un puntero y asignando la dirección del primer elemento del array al puntero

```
 int *p;

 p = arreglo;
 while (*p != valor) {
    p++;
  }

  if (*p == valor) {
       
  }else {
   
  }
```

El uso del   while se ejecuta mientras el valor almacenado en el puntero sea diferente al valor buscado, e incrementa el puntero apuntará al siguiente elemento del array, y la verificación se utiliza para comprobar si el valor en el puntero es igual al valor buscado.

```
int buscar(int *arreglo, int valor) {
  int *p = arreglo;
  while (*p != valor) {
    p++;
  }

  if (*p == valor) {
    return *p;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

**main....**

```
int hallar;
hallar  = buscar(arreglo, 5);

  if (hallar  == -1) {
    printf("El número no fue encontrado");
  } else {
    printf("El número encontrado es %d", hallar );
  }
```

Y el  while se detendrá cuando encuentre el valor buscado. Esto ocurre porque está accediendo a la memoria utilizando un puntero en la array. Cuando no encuentre el número, recorrerá toda la array

* **El número** `5` **es solo un ejemplo del número que se encontrará.**

* **Esta solución no es la mejor si el array es muy grande,  que el   while se volverá lento.**